# How to vertically align the text in table cell?

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

I am trying to get a table cell with vertical text alignment.

My current code is:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|}
\hline
\cellcolor{gray!20}Hardware\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Is there an easy solution to center the text vertically?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with "center the text vertically", since it is a single line in a narrow row... Did you mean horizontally?

Comment: @JLDiaz With my code, the text in the row was not vertically centered. It was a lot closer to the upper line then to the lower one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a `tabu` environment instead of `tabularx` the solution is as follows:

```
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth{|X[1,m,j]|} % m = vertical alignment, j = justified (horizontal alingmnet
\hline
\cellcolor{gray!20}Hardware\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
```

if you want additional vertical space you can specify `\tabulinesep=^Xmm_Ymm` at the beginning of the document

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelK you're welcome :)